# Trigger Argo Workflow with webhook

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj, github-webhook, argo-events

I have a use case where I want to trigger a argo workflow when github push events occur.
So far from what I understand the following would be the steps of my approach,

- Create Github webhook
- and then create the following in kubernetes

Event source(receives event from webhook and writes to event bus) -> Event Bus -> Sensor(listen to event from event bus & trigger the actions) -> trigger workflow template

Now, I have a few questions,

1. Can multiple event sources use same event bus?
2. How are we connecting event source to argo & to the github webhook? Are we creating a service & ingress from event source?
   Are there any examples or documentations available for this?

After spending a couple of days, I am still confused how to bridge the gaps between these pieces.
I am a little new to the argocd, so it will be helpful if you could point out the gaps in my understanding.

Comment: Removed argocd tag. You can use EventSource and Workflow(Template) resources in a github repo, and have ArgoCD manage them, but that is tangential to the question being asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going through official documentation :
https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/eventsources/setup/github/

It explains that once Event source is created, it automatically creates a service and a pod. The name for the service is in **{event-source-name}-eventsource-svc** format.

We can then further create an ingress to access it from argo endpoint.

https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/eventsources/naming/ This further explains how to create Event source correctly.

Finally, we can create a sensor file and define trigger conditions if any (https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/sensors/trigger-conditions/).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).